# How to redirect commands glued with && into the same file?

Tags: bash

This is what I wrote; for example,

```
ls > out && cat * > out
```

However, I don't like to duplicate codes (the real case is much more complicated), so I've tried

```
{ ls  &&  cat * } > out
```

Sadly, it did not work, since it doesn't conform to the Bash syntax, so how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your command grouping syntax is incorrect, you need to have `;` before the closing brace:

```
{ ls  &&  cat * ;}
```

If you are using a subshell, `()` like `(ls  &&  cat *)` then the `;` is not needed but spawning a subshell is redundant here IMO.

---

Next problem is that while globbing (`*`) the output file `out` is also being counted, as the file would be created by shell (`>out`) before the expansion happens or any other command runs (and `cat` will presumably warn you about the input/output file being same as far as `out` is concerned). To solve this problem:

- you can use the `GLOBIGNORE` environment variable to let `bash` know the patterns to ignore while doing globbing:

  ```
  GLOBIGNORE=out; { ls  &&  cat * ;} >out
  ```
- or use `extglob` option to explicitly exclude `out` from expansion:

  ```
  shopt -s extglob; { ls  &&  cat !(out) ;} >out
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem with the `>>` (append to file) operator like this:

`ls > out && cat * >> out`.

Or with parentheses:

`(ls && cat *) > out`.

Comment: Well, it is one-letter longer than what I think, but I am curious whether I can write `out` only once.

Comment: Yes you can: `(ls && cat *) > out`

Comment: Thanks for the clue.